# Flask render_template where HTML is in S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask

Can I have templates stored in S3 send to render_template ?

```
application_root = config.get_application_root()
static_folder = os.path.join(application_root, 'static')
template_folder = os.path.join(application_root, 'templates')
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static', static_folder=static_folder, template_folder=template_folder)
```

Easy solution would be to download s3 objects to a server directory and point render_template to pick from that directory.

I am wondering if this intermediate step is ever required. I have web_content passed down as pre-built HTML files and do not generate them. Can I send HTML as a string to render_template without actually having a HTML file?

```
/flask_folder 
----/app.py
----/templates/
----/static/

/my_external_template_folder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `render_template_string` instead of `render_template`:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.render_template_string